# Multiple Mailing Addresses Based on Time of Year

Tags: civimember, addresses, address-labels

Is there a way to add multiple mailing addresses to a membership record?

Say a member is in Florida during the Winter and Colorado during the Summer, is there a way to add the second mailing address? I mean, I suppose we can add the address in billing or notes, but was curious to see if anyone came across this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also add the two adresses as to different adress types. One is set as primary, and then you need some help on changing what adress is primary, based on time. I do think CiviRules could help you with that, giving a specific time of the year, where you change what adress is set as primary. If you want to go that route, let me know and I could help you with giving tip on specific trigger and condition to use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

But no, I do not recommend it, because of the overhead cost.

You could simply add a new adress type. And then you could have a custom field where you can set the time span for this adress to be used. Then, every time you want to send something in the postal mail, you need to search for this exception, and act after it. Or even write an extension, or pay someone to do it for you.

However, I don't think that it is any good idea to change such a crucial aspect of your workflow, over probably 1-2 cases. Then the overhead cost of working hours and complexity soon is much bigger than the benefit of those donors.

So, yes you could technically adapt CiviCRM to do it, but I would have reconsidered the cost/benefit ratio of doing it.